# Search restaurants by delivery area in a rails app (2)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, search, many-to-many, area

I want to search restaurants by delivey_area in a ruby on rails app.. I created a Many-to-Many Relationship.. In console everything is working but when i select an area in my search form it is not working.. I think i have something wrong in restaurants controller

```
## restaurant.rb
class Restaurant < ApplicationRecord
 has_and_belongs_to_many :areas
end

## area.rb
class Area < ApplicationRecord
 has_and_belongs_to_many :restaurants
end 

## migration (for rails 5.0)


  class CreateJoinTableAreaRestaurant < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    create_join_table :areas, :restaurants do |t|
      # t.index [:area_id, :restaurant_id]
      # t.index [:restaurant_id, :area_id]
    end
  end
end


# in view:
<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :delivery_areas %>
  <%= f.collection_check_boxes :area_ids, Area.all, :id, :name do |b| %>
    <div class="collection-check-box">
      <%= b.check_box %>
      <%= b.label %>
    </div>
  <% end %>
</div>

## restaurants_controller.rb
def index
  @restaurants = Restaurant.all.order("created_at DESC")
  if params[:area].blank? 
    @restaurants = Restaurant.all.order("created_at DESC")
  else 
    @area_id = Area.find_by(name: params[:area]).id 
    @restaurants = Restaurant.where(:area_id => @area_id).order("created_at DESC")
  end 
end

## search form
<ul class="dropdown-menu scrollable-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1" style="width: 440px;">
                  <% @areas.each do |area| %>
                    <li>
                      <%= link_to area.name, restaurants_path(area: area.name), class: "link" %>
                    </li>
                  <% end %>
</ul>
```

Comment: What's `@areas`?

Comment: "Not working" - can you be more specific? What do you expect, what happens instead?

Comment: The areas I select in restaurant form.. It works just for one restaurant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your migration code is not suppose to have relationship defined in it.

[From Rails API:](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods/has_and_belongs_to_many)

```
class CreateDevelopersProjectsJoinTable < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :developers_projects, id: false do |t|
      t.integer :developer_id
      t.integer :project_id
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Yes! You are right! But it is still not working.. I think i have to modify something in restaurant controller and the search form